# Zend Framework: Method "getDbTable" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've implemented the guestbook example from the reference guide, and am now trying to extend it with edit functionality.

I've added this to the GuestbookController:

```
    public function editAction()
{
    $model    = new Application_Model_Guestbook();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
   if ($request->isPost()) { 
       Print_r('posted');die();
   }
    $model = Application_Model_GuestbookMapper::find($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'), $model);
    $form = new Application_Form_Guestbook(array('model' => $model));

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

And have altered the view index to provide a link to the edit action:

```
<?php foreach ($this->entries as $entry): ?>
    <?php $url = $this->url(
         array(
            'controller' => 'guestbook',
            'action'     => 'edit',
            'id'=>$entry->id
        ),
        'default',
        true) 
    ?>
<dt><?php echo $this->escape($entry->email) ?></dt>
<dd><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $this->escape($entry->comment) ?></a></dd>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The mapper is standard - straight copy and paste from the reference guide.

When I click through (http://quickstart/guestbook/edit/id/1) I am confronted with an exception: [Method "getDbTable" does not exist and was not trapped in __call() ]

getDbTable() is called by the find() function which is in the same file. Why then can it not find getDbTable()?

I'm running: PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze1, Zend Engine v2.3.0,  Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)

Comment: because you are calling it statically and find is not a static method

Comment: public function find($id, Application_Model_Guestbook $guestbook)
    {
        $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
        if (0 == count($result)) {
            return;
        }
        $row = $result->current();
        $guestbook->setId($row->id)
                  ->setEmail($row->email)
                  ->setComment($row->comment)
                  ->setCreated($row->created);
    }

Comment: Sorry, that formatting is horrible! See the code at [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html) for a legible version.

I'm following an example call to find() which I found elsewhere. My limited understanding suggests that as long as I pass an  Application_Model_Guestbook reference in as the parameter, the object will be affected by the method.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why it does work until the call to another method is made? I would have expected that if it's not able to be called statically, it would have errored at the point of being called rather than attempting to run?

Comment: in php you are able to call the function statically even without declaring it so. You get notices and warnings though. However the main problem is that in static methods you do not have access to `$this` but you can easily make static functions from with non-static: `$self=new NonstaticClass();` and replace all `$this` with `$self`

Answer (score 0):

your class Application_Model_GuestbookMapper needs method getDbTable()

Comment: It has that method already - it's there in the reference guide. See here for the full listing: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

Comment: i already know but you've made a mistake somewhere or you don't have read entirely. Whatever, the exception say : your method getDbTable() is not defined, so look after that